# How to correctly wire a SilentStepStick (TMC2130) to Arduino? (Noob question)

Tags: stepper-motor, stepper-driver

Ingredients:
1) Arduino Uno
2) SilentStepStick Stepper Driver (TMC2130)  ([datasheet](https://www.trinamic.com/fileadmin/assets/Products/ICs_Documents/TMC2130_datasheet.pdf))
3) Fully Independent 24V and 5V power supplies
3) Driver code from: [watterott](https://github.com/watterott/SilentStepStick/blob/master/software/TMC2130.ino)
4) [Board pinouts](https://github.com/watterott/SilentStepStick/blob/master/hardware/SilentStepStick-TMC2130_v11.pdf)

[image]

I've wired up the TMC2130 driver board straight to an Arduino for bench testing.
+24V is connected to VM, and +5V connected to Vio.

Question: How to connect the ground's? Documentation seemed vague. There are two GND pins. Should the the -ve leads from each of the two power supplies be connected, one to each ground?  Or should only one ground, from one power supply be connected, to avoid any ground loops?

Sorry I know this will be a super easy question for someone. Thanks

Comment: We seem to be missing a datasheet link for the SilentStick device. An image of the pinout in your question would save us all some browser work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All GNDs (from logic and motor supply) should be connected together, so they have the same ground reference.
Also pay attention to the power up and down sequence of the supply voltages:
http://learn.watterott.com/silentstepstick/pinconfig/#powering

Comment: Please don't provide an answer that depends heavily on a link to another site...these links tend to go 404 without warning. Instead, summarize the important information in your answer.